# (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Serve

Tags: c#, sql-server

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions here

Answer (score 0):

There may be many caused to get error 40. Fews are listed below

1. make sure server is up and instance you are getting is running
2. Check your firewall setting if firewall block your SQL Server port
3. Enable TCP/IP protocol